# How to call .pyc function from C or C++?

Tags: c++, python, c

I have .pyc files I know functions inside it.

I need to call those function from C/ C++
I tried using **PyImport_Import** but it returns NULL.

```
pName = PyString_FromString("test");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName );
```

if I call **pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("py_ffile");** then it's working fine for .py files. But I don't want to call function from .py. I want to call it from .pyc file.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/) a C++ library which enables seamless interoperability between C++ and the Python programming language may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but you could consider using [Cython](http://cython.org/). It will compile your code to C, and you'll have no problem to use it from a C++ program.

Answer (score 1):

The path where your py file is located could be unknown. Trying to add your path by using sys like this, if you are using Boost Python:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys"); 
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"your path here\")");
```

or use this one:

```
PySys_SetPath("your path here");
```

And like this, if you are using directly the python dll:

```
SetSysPath("your path here");
```

and then try again with `PyImport_Import`